# How to delete some text in-between a string in a cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have some company addresses in an excel - here is how one of the cells look like. The number of company addresses in any cell varies.

```
abc
United Kingdom
Main Phone: 1234567
Main Fax: 63273818
Other Phone: 53177188

dfr
China
Main Phone: 2345671
Main Fax: 632738188

rtg
United States
Main Phone: 2434571
Main Fax: 3278188
Other Phone: 31771988

What I want as a outcome is 

abc
United Kingdom

dfr
China

rtg
United States
```

I have researched for this; however, could not find anything. I am trying to find a way to get the position of "Main" and the empty line and then delete the text in between. I tried with `CHAR(10) & CHAR(13)`..but those did not work. Any help in this regard would be welcome. Many thanks.

P.S>> If anyone can suggest any VBA code to do work, that would be also useful. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Function:

```
Function remo(txt As String) As String

    txt1 = Split(txt, Chr(10) & Chr(10))

    For i = LBound(txt1) To UBound(txt1)

        remo = remo & Left(txt1(i), InStr(1, txt1(i), "Main") - 1) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
        Debug.Print txt2

    Next

End Function
```

[image]

[Here you will find how to add a Custom Function In Excel](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-create-custom-excel-functions/)

Comment: Thanks, Mikku... as I mentioned, all the text are in one cell. So I really can't use the Left function, it will delete everything starting from Main..which I don't want. I want to delete in-between texts as there are multiple addresses in one cell.

Comment: Okay I have changed the Answer

Comment: Thanks, Mikku .. I just noticed that I am facing one issue ..which is if any of the addresses (of the multiple ones in one cell) does not have Main in it, then it's throwing error...is there any way out of that?

Comment: I Can't say without looking at the Data. Also, this code is very specific to the Input type. Maybe You can ask another question with the new Error that you are facing.