# Error while deleting unnecessary text from cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have some company addresses in an excel - here is how one of the cells look like. The number of company addresses in any cell varies.

```
abc
United Kingdom
Main Phone: 1234567
Main Fax: 63273818
Other Phone: 53177188

dfr
China


rtg
United States
Main Phone: 2434571
Main Fax: 3278188
Other Phone: 31771988

What I want as a outcome is 

abc
United Kingdom

dfr
China

rtg
United States
```

I have asked this before as well. And someone has been nice enough to share this code

```
Function remo(txt As String) As String 
    txt1 = Split(txt, Chr(10) & Chr(10))

    For i = LBound(txt1) To UBound(txt1)    
        remo = remo & Left(txt1(i), InStr(1, txt1(i), "Main") - 1) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
        Debug.Print txt2
    Next
End Function
```

However, this only works when each of the address (within a cell) has "Main" in it. If not, then it throws error. Here is the link to my first question [How to delete some text in-between a string in a cell in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000146/how-to-delete-some-text-in-between-a-string-in-a-cell-in-excel/57000174?noredirect=1#comment100535237_57000174) . It would be great if someone could help to fix this one. Many thanks.

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Additionally you always need to tell which error you get and in which line. We can only help if we know what *exactly* is wrong.

Comment: I totally get your point and I agree that I probably need to learn how to ask a question (though in this case, I have done enough research before I asked that question). I think you also need to learn how to respond to any person (if you really want to, no one actually forced you to comment), and more so if the person is new in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See if this Works:**

Added a If Condition to check for Main.

```
Function remo(txt As String) As String

    txt1 = Split(txt, Chr(10) & Chr(10))

    For i = LBound(txt1) To UBound(txt1)

        If InStr(1, txt1(i), "Main") > 1 Then
            remo = remo & Left(txt1(i), InStr(1, txt1(i), "Main") - 1) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
        Else: remo = remo & txt1(i) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
        End If

    Next

End Function
```

You should try and play with the code, to make it useful.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked...I am not into VBA code...I was actually looking out a way where I can use some excel functions to do these...tried Left, Right, Mid... was not really getting the result I wanted. As those were not working, i thought probably some VBA code might work on this. This totally worked - I can see that we can do quite a bit with this, will try to learn some. Thanks again.

Comment: @md2 ...No worries, you can think on lines how this VBA is working and make some functions in Excel. Anyways, accept the answer :)